# python3 wired behavior of subprocess.Popen and threading

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, ping

I want to write a python script to ping some servers in parallel using threading and subprocess.Popen. In subprocess.Popen I called "/bin/ping" program to ping server. After ping the server, I stored the latency result to a Queue. I have 16 servers, but every time I started the multithreading script, I got less than 16 results. Some ping return result haven't stored to the queue, some threading has finished before some ping return result store to the queue. The following is my script.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import platform
import subprocess
import re
import threading
from pprint import pprint
from queue import Queue

vultr_domain = {
                "(Asia)Seoul, Korea[韩国 首尔]"     :   "sel-kor-ping.vultr.com",
                "(Asia)Tokyo, Japan[日本 东京]"     :   "hnd-jp-ping.vultr.com",
                "Singapore[新加坡]"                 :   "sgp-ping.vultr.com",
                "(AU) Sydney, Australia[悉尼]"      :   "syd-au-ping.vultr.com",
                "(EU) Frankfurt, DE[德国 法兰克福]" :   "fra-de-ping.vultr.com",
                "(EU) Amsterdam, NL[荷兰 阿姆斯特丹]"   :   "ams-nl-ping.vultr.com",
                "(EU) London, UK[英国 伦敦]"            :   "lon-gb-ping.vultr.com",
                "(EU) Paris, France[法国 巴黎]"         :   "par-fr-ping.vultr.com",
                "Seattle, Washington[美东 西雅图]"      :   "wa-us-ping.vultr.com",
                "Silicon Valley, Ca[美西 加州 硅谷]"    :   "sjo-ca-us-ping.vultr.com",
                "Los Angeles, Ca[美西 加州 洛杉矶]"     :   "lax-ca-us-ping.vultr.com",
                "Chicago, Illinois[美东 芝加哥]"        :   "il-us-ping.vultr.com",
                "Dallas, Texas[美中 德克萨斯州 达拉斯]" :   "tx-us-ping.vultr.com",
                "New York / New Jersey[美东 新泽西]"    :   "nj-us-ping.vultr.com",
                "Atlanta, Georgiaa[美东 亚特兰大]"      :   "ga-us-ping.vultr.com",
                "Miami, Florida[美东 迈阿密]"           :   "fl-us-ping.vultr.com"
}

# 存放结果
q = Queue()

def linux_call_ping(server, ipaddr = "fl-us-ping.vultr.com"):

    ping = subprocess.Popen(["/bin/ping", "-c","2", ipaddr], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

    if ping[0]:
        # ping成功，但不一定能通
        #print(ping[0].decode())
        packet_loss = "(\d+)% packet loss"
        match_receive = re.search(packet_loss, ping[0].decode())
        packet_loss_rate = match_receive.groups()[0]

        if packet_loss_rate != '100':
            rtt = "rtt min/avg/max/mdev = (.*?) ms"
            rtt_rec = re.search(rtt, ping[0].decode())
            result = rtt_rec.groups()[0].split('/')[:3]
            result.append(packet_loss_rate)
        else:
            result = [999,999,999,100]

    else:
        # ping失败
        print(ping[1].decode())
        result = [999,999,999,100]

    q.put((server, float(result[1])))
    print("[+] {} ping stoped.".format(server))


def linux_ping_thr(q):
    while not q.empty():
        server, domain = q.get()
        try:
            print("[+] ", server, " ping started.")
            linux_call_ping(server, domain)
            
        except:
            print('[*]', server, " ping failed.")

def main():

    dq = Queue()

    server_latency = {}

    # 单线程
    # for server, domain in vultr_domain.items():
    #     
    #     result = linux_call_ping(domain)
    #     print(server, '\tmin: ', result[0], '\tavg: ', result[1], '\tmax: ', result[2], '\tloss rate: ', result[3])
    #     server_latency[server] = float(result[1])
    
    # 多线程
    for server, domain in vultr_domain.items():
        dq.put((server, domain))

    for i in range(6):
        threads = []
        try:
            thr = threading.Thread(target=linux_ping_thr, args=(dq, ))
            thr.start()
            threads.append(thr)
            
        except:
            print('[*] ping failed.')

    # for thr in threads:
    #     thr.start()
    for thr in threads:
        thr.join()
    
    print("Length: ", q.qsize())
    while not q.empty():
        s, l = q.get()
        server_latency[s] = l

    pprint(server_latency)
    # min_latency = min(server_latency, key=server_latency.get)
    # print(min_latency)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I move the `thr.start()` to a loop, just like the comment. Then the script runs very slow, like single thread.

I think may be the problem is subprocess and threading, but I don't konw how to solve it.

Here is the output.

```
[+]  (Asia)Seoul, Korea[韩国 首尔]  ping started.
[+]  (Asia)Tokyo, Japan[日本 东京]  ping started.
[+]  Singapore[新加坡]  ping started.
[+]  (AU) Sydney, Australia[悉尼]  ping started.
[+]  (EU) Frankfurt, DE[德国 法兰克福]  ping started.
[+]  (EU) Amsterdam, NL[荷兰 阿姆斯特丹]  ping started.
[+] (Asia)Seoul, Korea[韩国 首尔] ping stoped.
[+]  (EU) London, UK[英国 伦敦]  ping started.
[+] (AU) Sydney, Australia[悉尼] ping stoped.
[+]  (EU) Paris, France[法国 巴黎]  ping started.
[+] (EU) Amsterdam, NL[荷兰 阿姆斯特丹] ping stoped.
[+]  Seattle, Washington[美东 西雅图]  ping started.
[+] (Asia)Tokyo, Japan[日本 东京] ping stoped.
[+]  Silicon Valley, Ca[美西 加州 硅谷]  ping started.
[+] Singapore[新加坡] ping stoped.
[+]  Los Angeles, Ca[美西 加州 洛杉矶]  ping started.
[+] (EU) Frankfurt, DE[德国 法兰克福] ping stoped.
[+]  Chicago, Illinois[美东 芝加哥]  ping started.
[+] Silicon Valley, Ca[美西 加州 硅谷] ping stoped.
[+]  Dallas, Texas[美中 德克萨斯州 达拉斯]  ping started.
[+] Seattle, Washington[美东 西雅图] ping stoped.
[+]  New York / New Jersey[美东 新泽西]  ping started.
[+] (EU) London, UK[英国 伦敦] ping stoped.
[+]  Atlanta, Georgiaa[美东 亚特兰大]  ping started.
[+] Los Angeles, Ca[美西 加州 洛杉矶] ping stoped.
[+]  Miami, Florida[美东 迈阿密]  ping started.
[+] Chicago, Illinois[美东 芝加哥] ping stoped.
[+] (EU) Paris, France[法国 巴黎] ping stoped.
[+] New York / New Jersey[美东 新泽西] ping stoped.
Length:  13
{'(AU) Sydney, Australia[悉尼]': 180.772,
 '(Asia)Seoul, Korea[韩国 首尔]': 109.185,
 '(Asia)Tokyo, Japan[日本 东京]': 94.31,
 '(EU) Amsterdam, NL[荷兰 阿姆斯特丹]': 250.362,
 '(EU) Frankfurt, DE[德国 法兰克福]': 269.163,
 '(EU) London, UK[英国 伦敦]': 257.464,
 '(EU) Paris, France[法国 巴黎]': 256.591,
 'Chicago, Illinois[美东 芝加哥]': 266.876,
 'Los Angeles, Ca[美西 加州 洛杉矶]': 220.391,
 'New York / New Jersey[美东 新泽西]': 274.922,
 'Seattle, Washington[美东 西雅图]': 219.727,
 'Silicon Valley, Ca[美西 加州 硅谷]': 213.939,
 'Singapore[新加坡]': 282.892}
[+] Miami, Florida[美东 迈阿密] ping stoped.
[+] Dallas, Texas[美中 德克萨斯州 达拉斯] ping stoped.
[+] Atlanta, Georgiaa[美东 亚特兰大] ping stoped.
```

Comment: It's hard to tell with this much code, but in general the test `while not q.empty()` is not a good idea in multithreaded work. If any of the worker threads take a long time to do their work, the queue would be reported as empty even though the work is not done. A better approach is to send each thread a "sentinel", a special value that indicates its work is done. (`None` is a good choice for this.) You can also just some tools like `multiprocessing.Pool` to parallelize work easily. It handles distributing the work for you.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. But I don't understand how to send each thread a "sentinel". Can you show me some examples?

Comment: You're putting a tuple onto the queue now, right? As in, `q.put((server, domain))`. You can instead place a special value, usually called a "sentinel", that tells the worker threads to exit. Something like `q.put(None)` or `q.put(())`, the empty tuple, would be good in this case. You would put one sentinel per worker. Each worker pops the next value from the queue, and, if it's `None` it exits. If it's something useful, it works on it like normal. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51228455/1354854.